# Laravel 5.4: project not working on online server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, web-hosting

I developed a web application with Laravel 5.4. Everything works fine on localhost, but when I uploaded it to freesubdomain.org, it gave me a strange error.

This is the error:

```
RuntimeException in Encrypter.php line 43:
The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
```

This is the screenshot of the error in further details.
[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GBQt.jpg)

this is the App settings in my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:T0EKPpY0kWQBmMcJb4qH0rynVHYr/S03TuTTTlJ2rYk=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://fareedshuja.uk.tn
```

This is Encryption key configuration in config/app.php file

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
```

Please note that I have changed the database configuration in .env file and I have also changed the application URL in config/app.php from

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/getajob/'),
```

to

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://fareedshuja.uk.tn/'),
```

Please Help.

Comment: Could be the .env variables were cached before the encryption info was created? Try running `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan config:cache` and see if they resolves things.

EDIT: If that doesn't work you can always generate a new key using `php artisan key:generate`. All these would be ran in the console on your server.

Comment: First you should run few command for clearing cache. Use these commands and then upload it to live server.
1. `php artisan config:cache` 
2. `php artisan config:clear` and 
3. `php artisan key:generate` this will generate new key for you.